# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fd'

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics, attributeerror

I am reading a Python tutorial, one of the exercises has me stuck. The description for the exercise is: "Read the following function and see if you can figure out what it does. Then run it." So I cannot really tell you what it's doing, I'm still working on that.

I only wrote the two first lines myself, it's a copy paste from said tutorial. Here is the code:

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()
turtle.mainloop()

def draw(t, length, n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    angle = 50
    t.fd(length*n)
    t.lt(angle)
    draw(t, length, n-1)
    t.rt(2*angle)
    draw(t, length, n-1)
    t.lt(angle)
    t.bk(length*n)

draw(5, 10, 15)
```

Gives traceback:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "D:\Directory\Python\Projects\Learning python\Exercises\Exercise
> 5.14.5.py", line 18, in <module>
>     draw(5, 10, 15)   File "D:\Directory\Python\Projects\Learning python\Exercises\Exercise 5.14.5.py", line 10, in draw
>     t.fd(length*n) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fd'
```

Comment: first argument passed to `draw` call is an integer - `t`. This argument overshadows your global variable `t = turtle.Turtle()`

Comment: @Rogalski I think you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because the first parameter is `5`, so the variable `t` has the value `5` in the function. The code then attempts to call `5.fd(length*n)`. Switch the first parameter to `t` when calling `draw`:

```
draw(t, 10, 15)
```